# Extjs4 link click functionality error

Tags: extjs4, hyperlink

i am working in extjs4. i have gridview as=

```
{
            margin : '10 0 5 100',
            xtype : 'grid',
            id : 'g2',
            //title : 'Educational Details',
            store : 'qb.qbquestionoptionStore',
            columns : [ {
                text : 'Options',
                dataIndex : 'option',
                flex : 1
            }, {
                text : 'Answer',
                dataIndex : 'isAnswer',
                flex : 2.5
            },{
                header : 'edit',
                renderer : function(val) {
                    return '<a href="#" id="edit">Edit</a>';
                }
            },
            {
            header : 'Remove',
            renderer : function(val) {
                return '<a href="#" id="remove">Remove</a>';
            }
        }
```

For these above edit and remove links i had written code in controller as-

deleterow : function(cmp) {
        cmp.mon(cmp.getEl(), 'click', function(event, target) {

```
        if (target.id == 'edit') {
            console.log('edit');
            listview = Ext.getCmp('g2');

            listview.on({
                itemClick : function(dv, record, item, index, e, opts) {
                    var view = Ext.widget('useredit');
                    view.down('form').loadRecord(record);

                }
            });

        }

        if (target.id == 'remove') {
            //alert("hello");
            listview = Ext.getCmp('g2');

            listview.on({
                itemClick : function(dv, record, item, index, e, opts) {
                    //var grid = button.up('g3');
                    var store = listview.getStore();
                    var selected = listview.getSelectionModel()
                            .getSelection();
                    console.log(selected);

                    if (selected && selected.length == 1) {
                        store.remove(selected);
                        console.log(store);
                    }
                }});}}, this, {
        delegate : "a"
    });},
```

But on both links click,same edit link functionality is executing. So how to execute specific function on specific link click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an ideal way to get the functionality you are looking for.  You are using the html `id` attribute, which is theoretically only supposed to be used one time on a page.  Also, you are doing some unnecessary hacks just to add click events to the dom elements, and that is not a best practice.

Here are 2 possibilities.  First, you could use an `Ext.grid.column.Action`, which allows you to use a `handler` function for each action.  This is a clean way to do things, and can look crisp with good icons for edit/remove.  The Sencha examples have your exact scenario as their actions, and you can see the documentation here: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Action

An alternative to this would be to add an `onclick` attribute to your links, and make that call the function you need on your controller, passing in the right arguments:

```
{
    header : 'edit',
    renderer : function(val, meta, rec) {
        return '<a href="#" onclick="MyApp.app.getController(\'MyController\').editRow(' + rec.get('id') + ')">Edit</a>';
    }
},
{
    header : 'Remove',
    renderer : function(val) {
        return '<a href="#" onclick="MyApp.app.getController(\'MyController\').removeRow(' + rec.get('id') + ')">Remove</a>';
    }
}
```

Then, in your controller, you can retrieve that record based on the id and do what you need to do with it:

```
editRow: function(recordId) {
    var view = Ext.widget('useredit'),
        record = Ext.getCmp('g2').getStore().findExact('id', recordId);
    view.down('form').loadRecord(record);
},

removeRow: function(recordId) {
    var store = Ext.getCmp('g2').getStore(),
        record = store.findExact('id', recordId);
    store.remove(record);
}
```

Comment: thanx for reply sir...I have app.js as="Ext.application({
requires: ['Ext.container.Viewport'],
name: 'Balaee',
appFolder: 'app',

  controllers: [
                   'Balaee.controller.qb.qbquestionController'
                 ],
launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', 
         {layout: 'auto',
            items: {
             
 xtype:'editView'}
        });
    }
});"  So when i am writing onclick="Balaee.app.getController(\'qb.qbquestionController\').editRow()" ,Its giving me error as "Balaee.app is undefined " So how to modify?

Comment: What version of ExtJS are you using?  With 4.2, your application.js file should look more like this: 

Ext.define('Balaee.Application', {
    name: 'Balaee',

    extend: 'Ext.app.Application',

    controllers: [
        'qb.qbquestionController'
    ],
 
    launch: function() { 
        Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
            layout: 'auto', 
            items: { xtype:'editView'} 
        });
    }
});

Comment: Sir,I am using extjs4.0 version.

Comment: If you are saying that you are using 4.0.0, then I strongly recommend updating your version, at a very minimum to 4.0.7.  4.1.3 is much faster, and 4.2.1 works very well out of the box, and those are much better options if it is possible for you to make the switch.